# How to add audio to a 10 second countdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, audio

First time posting on here so go easy.
I am having some problems with a recent project. I am trying to create a countdown as the landing page with audio sounds for each number (street fighter 2 sound effects if anyone is familiar). I have managed to get the countdown to work and it will work but only at the click of a button as this is the only way I could get it to work.

Like I said this is not the desired effect as once the countdown finishes I want it to load the main page. Also in regards to adding the sound to each individual number, I have absolutely no idea where to start!

This is my current JS for it

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const timeLeftDisplay = document.querySelector('#time-left')
    const startBtn = document.querySelector('#start-button')
    let timeLeft = 10

    function countDown (){
        setInterval(function(){
            if(timeLeft <= 0){
                clearInterval(timeLeft = 0)
            }
            timeLeftDisplay.innerHTML = timeLeft
            timeLeft -= 1
        }, 1000)
    }

    startBtn.addEventListener('click', countDown)

} )
```

This is the current HTML

```
<script type= "text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/script.js"></script>
<title>Bro-nament</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
    <h1 class="bro-title"> TIME TILL BRO - DOWN</h1>
    <h2 id="time-left"> 10 </h2>
    <button id="start-button"> <i class="fas fa-fist-raised">   Continue?  </i> <i class="fas fa-fist-raised"></i></button>
```

[Current page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYCLF.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server, you need to name your audio files with a number for all of them and use the value of time variable to increment and get the url of the file for each every seconde.

Like :

- 9.mp3
- 8.mp3
- 7.mp3
- 6.mp3
- ....

Once the counter is to 0, you redirect where the url you want.

```js
let time = 10;
countdown();

function countdown() {
  // we upadate number text
  document.querySelector('#time-left').textContent = --time;
 
  // if count is equal to 0 (end of counter) 
  if (time === 0) {
     time = 10;
     // we redirect to this url
     window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
     // we stop the loop
     return false;
  }
  
  //console.log(time);
  
  // we set the url of audio file for each seconde
  const audio = new Audio("https://srv-store5.gofile.io/download/RFgvcw/" + time + ".mp3");
  // if you only want one, u dont need the const time
  //const audio = new Audio("https://srv-store5.gofile.io/download/RFgvcw/1.mp3");  
  
  audio.play();

  setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}
```

```css
#time-left {
    font-size: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: auto 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="time-left"></div>
```

Comment: That's amazing, I went about it at a slightly different angle but it helped me a lot. Thank you